# what happens after using function with noInterrupts that is called from interrupt

Tags: arduino

I have a function that for some other code paths must use `interrupts()` and `noInterrupts()` (it is a custom buffer class "put" or "get" function).

What happens if I put packets to this buffer FROM interrupt (let's say I2C)? Obviously, at the end of my buffers "put" function, `interrupts()` will be called. But after returning from "put", I'm still inside interrupt routine of I2C interrupt handler! So, will arduino act as if also this (I2C handler) interrupt is "cleared", and start allowing other (if any) interrupts to execute, or, will it not have any effects untill also I2C interrupt handler is finished?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will arduino act as if also this (I2C handler) interrupt is "cleared", and start allowing other (if any) interrupts to execute?

Yes.